# How can I verify that my DoS attack is effective?

Tags: network, ddos, denial-of-service, wireshark, flooding

I was trying to simulate a DoS attack on the CORE network emulator using hping3 (Ubuntu). The topology is like three PCs connected by a router. The client's IP is 10.0.0.20/24, The server's IP is 10.0.1.20/24 and the attacker's IP is 10.0.2.20/24.

I ran a script to turn on services for the server and a looped curl command that is run every two seconds on the client. Now I have used the hping3 command (`hping3 -S --flood -V -p 1025 10.0.1.20`) on the attacker's machine.

I can see the wireshark captures the TCP packets that are flooded due to hping command. However, according to the norm, the client should stop receiving the HTML code from the server as the server is overloaded with requests. Somehow the client is getting a response from the server.

Does that mean my DoS attack simulation failed? How should I rectify this?

Comment: The DoS you attempt is to overload the target system so that it runs out of resources. But in your setup your run everything on a single physical system, which means you share the resources between attacker, attacked system and observer. Thus any slowdown and resource shortage introduced by the attack also affects the attacker and the observer themselves. Which is obviously not a good setup to simulate resource starving attacks.

Comment: If you want to overload resources, then you look to see if those resources are overloaded ... CPU, memory, bandwidth, etc... Just looking at the effects on the client side is not complete or efficient.